# Assigning value to a variable using the rnorm function in r

Tags: r

I have a very basic query. I do not understand how values are being assigned to the variable "purchase". 
1.) Since "ads" has a sample size of 100 I assume there is a loop being run. Is that so?
2.) also the rnorm function generates a normal distribution with 100 samples. How is a value being assigned from this distribution to the variable "purchase"?

```
ads = sample(c("ad1","ad2","ad3"),size=100,replace=T)
purchase = ifelse(ads=='ad1',rnorm(100,mean=50,sd=80),
                ifelse(ads=='ad2',rnorm(100,mean=600,sd=80),rnorm(100,mean=200,sd=80)))
```

Comment: `ifelse` takes all its arguments to have the same length.  Here test,  'yes', 'no' are of the same length -100.  Whereever the 'test' condition is met, the corresponding 'rnorm value is replaced.  You can check by `v1 <- rnorm(100,mean=50,sd=80); v2 <- rnorm(100,mean=600,sd=80); v3 <- rnorm(100,mean=200,sd=80); ifelse(ads == 'ad1', v1, NA)`

Comment: So is the value to be assigned just chosen randomly from the 100 samples of the normal distribution that we generate?

Comment: Not chosen randomly, chosen based on the `ifelse` condition, `ads == 'ad1'`. Imagine that `ads` has length equal to 4 and that the condition result is `c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)`. Then the 1st and 4th element sampled from the normal will be chosen.